# values not caltulating properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created function to devide the values but the problem is that when place function parseInt and check it is avoiding numbers after (,) like if the value is 345,00.95 after using parseInt() it is becoming as 645 can any one help me out why is this happening

```
  function liquid(val) {
    $(".overlay").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "portfolio/getPortfolioInfo.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "portfolio_id=" + val,
        type: "post",
        error:function(){
            $(".overlay").hide();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(".overlay").hide();
            $("#liquidity").html(data.liquidity);
            var num_left = data.liquidity / parseFloat(<?php echo $company['price']; ?>);
            var rounded_value   = Math.round(num_left);
            $(".shares_left").html("<p>You can buy up to " + rounded_value + " </p>");
            console.log("liquidity" + parseInt(data.liquidity) + "rate" +parseFloat(<?php echo $company['price']; ?>));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: because this is not a valid number format: `345,00.95` change it to `34500.95` first

Comment: use this parseFloat(('345,00.95').replace(/,/g,'')); or parseFloat((data.liquidity).replace(/,/g,'')); in your case

Comment: @KarthikGanesan great it worked for me can you please post as answer and explain me if you can fo rmy future refference that would be great for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considering the sample you provided

> parseInt(345,00.95)

will output only the initial integer part that being

> 345

in your case

even if you had removed the initial `','` that is if your number was `parseInt(34500.95)` that will still give out just `34500` ignoring the decimal part

to achieve what you are looking for first remove all the `','` from your data

to do that use replace with a regex that matches all `','` within your data

> (data.liquidity).replace(/,/g,'')

this will output

> 34500.95

and then apply  **parseFloat** to it

so your final code should be **`parseFloat((data.liquidity).replace(/,/g,''));`**